# NoMethodError in Users#index undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot get the values of my profiles table in the index view of user.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

my view in index:

```
<%= user.surname%> <%= user.name%>
<%= @profile.bio%>
```

I have the relations has_one: profile in user and belongs_to: user in profile

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined the `@profile` instance variable in your controller. I assume this is in a `@users.each do |user|` block in your `index.html.erb` view. If you modify your view as follows it should work:

```
<%= user.profile.bio %>
```